# OpenGL Squares and Arrows

Tags: c++, opengl

i'm trying to create a square and on top of it  i'm creating an arrow. its like a 2D meter something similar to that. But i don't know how to create the arrow on top of the square.

```
int count = 1;
for (float y = 1; y < 11; y++) {
    y1 = y1 - 0.51;
    y2 = y2 - 0.51;

    float x2 = -2.0;
    for (float x1 = -2.5; x1 < 2.5; x1 = x1 + 0.51) {

        glColor3f(windy[count], 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
        glVertex2f(x1, y2);
        glVertex2f(x2, y2);
        glVertex2f(x2, y1);
        count = count + 1;
        x2 = x2 + 0.51;



    }
}

glutSwapBuffers();
glEnd(); //End the glBegin Function
```

And this is what i want to be on top of it.

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);//start drawing a line loop
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//left of window
        glVertex3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);//bottom of window
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//right of window
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//top of window
        glEnd();//end drawing of line loop
```

Comment: you shouldn't swap buffers in-between `glBegin` and `glEnd`

Comment: @Java_NewBie: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you swap buffers before `glEnd()` call:

```
int count = 1;
for (float y = 1; y < 11; y++) {
    y1 = y1 - 0.51;
    y2 = y2 - 0.51;

    float x2 = -2.0;
    for (float x1 = -2.5; x1 < 2.5; x1 = x1 + 0.51) {

        glColor3f(windy[count], 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
        glVertex2f(x1, y2);
        glVertex2f(x2, y2);
        glVertex2f(x2, y1);
        count = count + 1;
        x2 = x2 + 0.51;
    }
}

//glutSwapBuffers(); // wrong place
glEnd(); //End the glBegin Function
glutSwapBuffers(); // Must be after draw operation
```

to draw arrow on the top of the shape must be even more:

```
int count = 1;
for (float y = 1; y < 11; y++) {
    y1 = y1 - 0.51;
    y2 = y2 - 0.51;

    float x2 = -2.0;
    for (float x1 = -2.5; x1 < 2.5; x1 = x1 + 0.51) {

        glColor3f(windy[count], 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
        glVertex2f(x1, y2);
        glVertex2f(x2, y2);
        glVertex2f(x2, y1);
        count = count + 1;
        x2 = x2 + 0.51;
    }
}

//glutSwapBuffers(); // wrong place
glEnd(); //End the glBegin Function

// draw arrow
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);//start drawing a line loop
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//left of window
        glVertex3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);//bottom of window
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//right of window
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//top of window
        glEnd();//end drawing of line loo


// atlast we can swap our buffers
glutSwapBuffers(); // Must be after draw operation
```

Comment: @Java_NewBie: Did my answer help you?